# Python: Get a variable vector from a list of classes

Tags: python, list, class, variables

I have a list full of classes of the same type:

```
class Example():

    def __init__(self, myVar):
        self.myVar = myVar
        # other variables and functions
        # ...
```

Following example shows the list:

```
myList = []
for i in range(0,10):
    myList.append(Example(i))
```

And now i want a quick way to get a new list with all myVar of all Example-classes.
I thoght of something like:

```
myVector = myList[:].myVar
```

But this doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to loop over `myList`. lists don't support vectorized operations. You could use a list comprehension as well.

Comment: OP, why would that work? `myList[:]` is a list object that doesn't contain a `myVar` attribute. Loop over `myList` and take the `.myVar` for each element: `[e.myVar for e in myList]`